# Using a Server in C#

Tags: c#

I made a program that saves information on .dat files.
On each time the program is closed the old information is replaced by the new information.
When I open the program, it reads the information from the dat files.

I want to create a server that I will be able to upload the .dat files to it and on each `Form_Close` the old information will be deleted from the sever and the new information will be uploaded to the server.
When I open the program, I want it to delete the .dat files on the computer and replace them by the information from the server.

What is the best choise of service for that kind of problem ?

I thought maybe I should use **Google Drive**.
But I don't know if it's a good choise.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: *How can I create that kind of server ?* In Visual Studio, choose File => New Project. Then write the code.

Comment: This question is way too broad and prone for opinion-based answers.

Comment: *what do you mean ?* [Roll up your sleeves and get to it](http://www.broughtonadvisory.com/_broughtonadvisorycom/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Success-Secret.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tons of options here, which one is better depends on your project and goals, but all of them will work.

1. You can use cloud drives, like google drive, dropbox, amazon s3 and so on.
   And there is 2 ways to use them.

   1. Just `File.Copy` your file to the local folder and let cloud client deal with it.
   2. Use cloud drive's API to upload file
2. You can buy an ftp/http hosting, or set up one of your own and upload files with c# `FtpClient` or `HttpClient`.
3. You can use `WebDAV`
4. You can copy your file to shared folder on the server.
5. You can write your own simple socket/http/ftp server. (with c# `HttpListener` for example)

Comment: How can I "let the cloud client deal with it" ?

Comment: @user2992413 did you ever use dropbox or google drive? When you install their client application it creates local folder and automatically synchronizes it with server. You just need to copy the file. In case it's too big and you want to make sure that it has been uploaded before your user shuts down the pc, you might be needing to add some code to determine upload status.

Comment: But I want the program to do it by itself

Comment: then use API https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put with 'HttpClient' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx